# How to loop a request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I recently started learning coding, and I wanted to know how I can multiply/loop this request instead of it being sent only once.

```
request({
    url: URL,
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body){
    if(error){
        console.log("Error!")
    } else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(chalk.green('Entered successfuly!'))
    }
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by "multiply/loop". When/how should be sent another request? You probably don't just want to DOS your own server.

Comment: Why would you want to loop requests? Recursion will take place and like Thomas said, DDoS attack. You would likely want to make a single request and loop through the data. Please update question with more information and code please. Good luck!

Comment: It's a request to a page where I want to get more views on, each request equals 1 view, I want to loop it so I don't have to restart the code over and over. Not sure if I explained it well, sorry.

Comment: so you want to scrape another page, imo. here's a good explanation https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop will call the function as fast as your computer can process it. Instead put it into a timeout that calls itself so you can regulate the requests.

```
function makeRequest(){
 request({
    url: URL,
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
 }, function (error, response, body){
    if(error){
        console.log("Error!")
    } else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(chalk.green('Entered successfuly!'))
    }
 })
 setTimeout(makeRequest,1000)
}
makeRequest()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The request can be sent many times over time using a setTimeout loop:

```
function sendRequest() {

  setTimeout(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/example',
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body){
        if(error){
            console.log("Error!")
        } else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            console.log(chalk.green('Entered successfuly!'))
        }
    });

    sendRequest();

  }, 1000);

}

sendRequest();
```

Or as an interval function:

```
function sendRequest() {

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/example',
      method: 'GET',
      json: true
  }, function (error, response, body){
      if(error){
         console.log("Error!")
      } else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log(chalk.green('Entered successfuly!'))
      }
  });

}

let interval = setInterval(sendRequest, 1000);
```

If you'd like to send the request a fixed number of times, the first function can be modified like that:

```
function sendRequest(i) {

  if (i > 0) {

    setTimeout(function() {

      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/example',
          method: 'GET',
          json: true
      }, function (error, response, body){
          if(error){
              console.log("Error!")
          } else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
              console.log(chalk.green('Entered successfuly!'))
          }
      });

      sendRequest(i - 1);

    }, 1000);

  }

}

sendRequest(3);
```